# Lambda with Multiple Joins returning strongly typed objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

Here is a simplified set of tables I'm working with described as classes.  I'm using T4 templates to create simple POCO's.  **I've removed all non-essential properties of all classes that might clutter up the question**.

```
public class MarketingPlan
{
  public guid MarketingPlanID { get; set; }
  public bool Disabled { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<MarketingPlanItem> MarketingPlanItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class MarketingPlanItem
{
    public System.Guid MarketingPlanItemID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid MarketingPlanID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid MarketingPlanItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> EmailTemplateID { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
    public virtual MarketingPlanItemType MarketingPlanItemType { get; set; }
}

public partial class EmailTemplate
{
    public System.Guid EmailTemplateID { get; set; }
}

public partial class MarketingPlanItemType
{
    public System.Guid MarketingPlanItemTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

The strongly-typed result I am trying to create does not need to be connected to Entity Framework context.  This is my attempt at the solution.

```
public MarketingPlan GetMarketingPlanWithItems(Guid marketingPlanID)
{
  var query = 
      this.Context
          .MarketingPlanItems
          .GroupJoin(this.Context.MarketingPlanItemTypes,
                     mpi => mpi.MarketingPlanItemTypeID,
                     mpit => mpit.MarketingPlanItemTypeID,
                     (mpi, mpit) =>
                     {
                       mpi.MarketingPlanItemType = mpit.FirstOrDefault();
                       return mpi;
                     })
          .GroupJoin(this.Context.EmailTemplates,
                     mpi => mpi.EmailTemplateID,
                     et => et.EmailTemplateID,
                     (mpi, et) =>
                     {
                       mpi.EmailTemplate = et.FirstOrDefault();
                       return mpi;
                     })
          .Where(mpi => mpi.Disabled == false);

  var result = 
      this.Context
          .MarketingPlans
          .GroupJoin(query,
                     mp => mp.MarketingPlanID,
                     mpi => mpi.MarketingPlanID,
                     (mp, mpi) =>
                     {
                       mp.MarketingPlanItems = mpi.ToList();
                       return mp;
                     })
          .Where(mp => mp.MarketingPlanID == marketingPlanID)
          .FirstOrDefault();

  return result;
}
```

Now I realize I can't use a real anonymous function in the `GroupJoin` because it throws the following error:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

I coded it this way in this example, because if I `new` a strongly typed object, I believe i'd have to populate every field which I'd rather not do.

The end result is to have; a `MarketingPlan` with it's `MarketingPlanItems` populated with only the ones that are not `Disable`, it's `EmailTemplate` either populated by the EmailTemplate or Null, and each MarketingPlanItem populated with it's `MarketingPlanItemType`.    The sql for this might look like (roughly):

```
SELECT
  mp.*,
  mpi.*,
  mpit.*,
  et.*
FROM
  MarketingPlan mp
  LEFT JOIN MarketingPlanItem mpi 
    on mp.MarketingPlanID = mpi.MarketingPlanID 
  INNER JOIN MarketingPlanItemType mpit 
    on mpi.MarketingPlanItemTypeID = mpit.MarketingPlanItemTypeID
  LEFT JOIN EmailTemplate et
    on mpi.EmailTemplateID = et.EmailTemplateID
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Entity Framework using Lambda without doing multiple requests to the database?

**UPDATE 1**

```
public MarketingPlan GetMarketingPlanWithItems(Guid marketingPlanID)
{
  MarketingPlan result = null;

  var query = this.Context.MarketingPlanItems
                          .Include("MarketingPlan")
                          .Include("MarketingPlanItemType")
                          .Include("EmailTemplate")
                          .Include("EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateCategory")
                          .Where(mp => !mp.Disabled
                                       && !mp.MarketingPlan.Disabled
                                       && mp.MarketingPlanID == marketingPlanID)
                          .ToList();

  var query2 = query.FirstOrDefault();

  if (query2 != null)
  {
    result = query2.MarketingPlan;
    result.MarketingPlanItems = query;
  }

  return result;
}
```

This ultimately returned what I needed.

Comment: That **is** a real anonymous function. It just isn't a one-expression-lambda-expression.

Comment: Do you really physically need to get the result as a new MarketingPlan with the enabled plans inside it's collection? I'm asking because that's ultimately creating a new Entity. Shouldn't you be returning just enabled plans, and have the consumer group as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just return the plan items?

Such as:

```
var items = this.Context.MarketingPlanItems
            .Where(x => !x.Disabled && !x.MarketingPlan.Disabled)
```

Each item returned already has an associated email template. Just consume it as `item.EmailTemplate`, no need for manual joins.

To that result you can ultimate group by `item.MarketingPlan.MarketingPlanID` in something like a `Dictionary<MarketingPlan, IList<MarketingPlanItem>>` or a custom `Type` of your own, that represents each plan with its enabled items, without actually needing to create any new entities.

Why not take advantage of the ORM to resolve relationships for you?
Beware of SELECT N+1 issues, and make sure EF is fetching all associated entities.
such as using:

```
this.Context.MarketingPlanItems
    .Include(i => i.MarketingPlan)
    .Include(i => i.EmailTemplate)
```

You can also write an extension method on your `MarketingPlan` type, to return an expression that returns enabled items on it, and use it with Linq as well.

Comment: The problem I am running into is that I still need the `MarketingPlanItem` as the result (because it has other properties I excluded because they were non-essential to the query, for example, title, summary, etc).

Comment: Correct, and the implementation I mentioned in fact returns entire MarketingPlanItems, which you can group by MarketingPlan as well, and have that entire object too. Include is used to ensure that EF get's those entire entities in one single query as joins, rather than lazy loading by ID afterwards, for every plan in the result.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you want to load related subitems for MarketingPlans.

Why don't you use Include()? Use something like this:

```
this.Context.MarketingPlans.Include("MarketingPlanItems.EmailTemplates")
```